# mosquitto - disable subscribing without authorization

Tags: acl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto version 1.4.10 with tls-certificate. I am using this plugin https://github.com/mbachry/mosquitto_pyauth to authorize a user.And it works well for mosquitto_pub ( as in, when someone tries to publish , it gets authorized by the module first ).

However, it seems that mosquitto_sub is able to subscribe to anything without authorizing. How do I force security when someone is just trying to access a topic in read only mode?

I  went through the mosquitto.conf file and cant seem to find anything related to this.

for example, I am able to subscribe like this:

```
mosquitto_sub --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca.crt --cert /etc/mosquitto/client.crt --key /etc/mosquitto/client.key -h ubuntu -p 1883 -t c/# -d
```

and able to see messages coming from some publisher like this:

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca.crt --cert /etc/mosquitto/client.crt --key /etc/mosquitto/client.key -h ubuntu -p 1883 -t c/2/b/3/p/3/rt/13/r/123 -m 32 -q 1
```

What I am trying to do is prevent mosquitto_sub reading all messages at root level without authorization .

the python code that does the authorization looks like this : ( auth data is stored in cassandra db )

```
import sys
import mosquitto_auth

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel


## program entry point from mosquitto...
def plugin_init(opts):
    global cluster, session, select_device_query
    conf = dict(opts)
    cluster = Cluster(['192.168.56.102'])
    session = cluster.connect('hub')
    select_device_query = session.prepare('SELECT * from devices where uid=?')
    select_device_query.consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM
    print 'Cassandra cluster initialized'


def acl_check(clientid, username, topic, access):

    device_data = session.execute(select_device_query, [username])

    if device_data.current_rows.__len__() > 0:
        device_data = device_data[0]
        # sample device data looks like this :
        # Row(uid=u'08:00:27:aa:8f:91', brand=3, company=2, device=15617, property=3, room=490, room_number=u'3511', room_type=13, stamp=datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 6, 29, 54, 723000))
        subscribable_topic = 'c/' + str(device_data.company) \
                             + '/b/' + str(device_data.brand) \
                             + '/p/' + str(device_data.property) \
                             + '/rt/' + str(device_data.room_type) \
                             + '/r/' + str(device_data.room) \
                             + '/#'

        matches = mosquitto_auth.topic_matches_sub(subscribable_topic, topic)
        print 'ACL: user=%s topic=%s, matches = %s' % (username, topic, matches)
        return matches

    return False
```

function `acl_check` seems to be always called when mosquitto_pub tries to connect, but never called when mosquitto_sub connects.
the C code behind this python module is here: https://github.com/mbachry/mosquitto_pyauth/blob/master/auth_plugin_pyauth.c

Comment: I assume you mean `mosquitto_sub` not `mosquitto_pub` in the second paragraph

Comment: my bad..yes, i meant mosquitto_sub

Comment: You might want to include the python code as well so we can see how you've implemented the ACL

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your mosquitto.conf

```
...
allow_anonymous false
...
```

This will stop users without credential from logging on to the broker.

You can also add an acl rule for the `anonymous` user if there are certain topics you would want unauthenticated clients to be able to see.

Comment: Hi,the user is not anonymous. he is an authenticated user. but he should not be authorized to subscribe to anything which he isnt allowed to . I have updated the question with the sub and pub commands.